# How to fix dead links in Interface builder

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

My app was all linked correctly. I launched it today and had a look at my 2 additional view, and their links are broken. It says the view is not defined in the class anymore, as well as one method I have still there is not being seen by interface builder?

How can these links be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure all the necessary ivars that needs to be exposed defined as `IBOutlet`? Also, are the methods have `IBAction` as the 'return type' ?

I assume this is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188645/view-wont-update-imageiphone-app) where your view is missing?

Comment: I have everything they way it was, all defined correctly, but for some reason now, 2 of my views, none of the buttons link up, none of the methods? But they are all there in the classes. IB cant even find them, and I have saved etc. Really confused.

Comment: Are you sure that your view is of whatever type your custom class is? Take a look at the identity tab in IB.

Comment: I'm confused. If they are all `UIView`, how do you link it up from your custom class? The type of your view has to be of your custom class type so that the outlets and actions appear in IB.

Comment: Im not sure I follow. Which is my custom class? I have 3 views, One in the ViewController class and then 2 which show and hide.

Comment: The weird thing is , all my classes work. My code is working, even the buttons which interface builder cannot find anymore, are working correctly?